# Как написать правильно конфигурацию EncodingFilter без WEB.XML

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

В моем проект конфигурация написана в WEB.XML, но я хочу чтобы oна была в моем JAVA классе.

Мой WEB.XML

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

У меня ошибка выходит как правильно его добавить в мой JAVA класс

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size}")

    private int maxFileSize;

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size}")

    private int maxRequestSize;

    @Autowired

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{HibernateConfig.class/*, SecurityConfig.class*/};

    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{WebMvcConfig.class};

    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};

    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter};
}


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде бы фильтр добавлен правильно. Нужно посмотреть текст ошибки, может станет яснее.

Comment: сейчас отправлю

Comment: добавил ошибку можете посмотреть,,

Comment: Похоже, что в импорте не тот класс Filter прописан. Должен быть import javax.servlet.Filter;